# Is it possible to receive rep awarded from bounty after hitting mortarboard on the same day?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I came pretty close to this situation not long ago, except I received my mortarboard as result of getting a bounty.  Also, I have received a mortarboard from a good question without receiving bounty points.

In short, **Are bounty rep points bounded by the daily limit?**

Comment: Given that bounties range from 50 to 500 rep, capping payouts at 200 would be pretty stupid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From: [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and **bounties are counted separately**.

So, no, they don't have anything with the limit.